# Passing data in React Router

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router

So I have a problem with passing data from one Component to another. So I have Free To Play Component which has is taking freetoplay array from json and rendering it on display. I have also a Link which should open up a Payment Route and pass the data from the Component that is pressed, In the Payment I have a filter function, which is fitering objects based on their id, Anyway when I press on the Link, it should render the image class and price, but it does not, I dont know why. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful. Cheers

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import data from "../data.json";

function Payment() {  
    const { productId } = useParams();
    const filteredData = data.filter((product) => product.id === productId)[0];
    return (
        <div  className='Payment'>
         <img src={filteredData.image}></img>
         <h1>{filteredData.price}</h1>
         <h1>{filteredData.name}</h1>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default Payment

import React from 'react'
import data from "./data.json";
import {
    
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { SearchContext } from './SearchContext';


function FreeToPlay() {
  const {filterProduct}=React.useContext(SearchContext);
    return (
        <>
          <div className='All' >
            {data[0].freetoplay.filter(filterProduct).map((product) => {
              return (
                <div className='f2p' key={product.id}>               
                    <img src={product.image}></img>
                    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                    <h5>{product.price}</h5>
                  <Link
            to={`/payment/${product.id}`}
            className='link'
           >
            Buy Now
           </Link>
        </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
}

export default FreeToPlay

json
[
  {
    "freetoplay": [{
        "id": "0",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "CS Go"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "6$",
        "name": "Fifa"
      }
    ],
 
    "action": [{
        "id": "2",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "doom"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "66$",
        "name": "cyberpunk"
      }
    ],
    
  }
]


this is the Route

 <Route exact path="/payment/:productId">
            <Payment/>
 </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing exact from route.